# How to set the locale for a process launched by CreateProcess()

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When launching a process with `CreateProcessW()`, is it possible to have the process created with a different MBCP locale/codepage then the one that is configured as the system-wide default code page?
In the target process, this should have the same effect as calling `_setmbcp()`.

The target process is not a unicode-enabled and uses a plain `main(int argc, char **argv)` entry point. I would like to be able to select the code page to which unicode arguments passed to `CreateProcessW()` are converted to be different from the system's default codepage for non-unicode programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (and it's been a long time since I've had to know this) the child process inherits the locale of the parent process (or thread therein) -- have you tried switching the thread locale, launching your process (and switching back)?

Answer (score 2):

I just came accross a Microsoft utility: [AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/apploc.mspx), which seems to address just that need...